# OpenMP: Will different memory locations speed up loops?

Tags: loops, for-loop, openmp

I have an OpenMP program that calculates variables in a loop.

```
int a[1000000];
int b[1000000];
int c[1000000];
int d[1000000];

#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(a,b,c,d)
for (i=0;i<1000000;++i)
{
d[i] = b[i]*a[i] + c[i]+10;
}
```

I used perf and perf said the bottleneck is in memory reading and writing.

First question: Is it possible to split the arrays A,B,C,D and put them into different memory banks using OpenMP?

Second question: If I split the arrays A,B,C,D into smaller arrays, will they speed up the execution of the loop?

Comment: You could use a struct with a,b,c,d to be more cache efficient.

Comment: @H4kor  Alignment seems to speed it up by 10%. But the efficiency(speedup/processors) is still bad < 50%.

Comment: Your code is clearly memory bound.  Reducing array size is only useful is you can reuse data in cache, but you have *no* reuse of data. Once a data is used, it is no longer needed and caches cannot help. Concerning the first question, it depends on your hardware. For most laptops and workstations, there is only one memory bank. Otherwise, on ccNUMA architectures, it generally helps.

Comment: This loop should clearly be vectorized (before you parallelize, since vectorization can reduce the required CPU time, whereas parallelizing just moves it around to get you an answer sooner), so stick " simd " after the "for" in your directive. But, as this is BW bound (as everyone is saying), it may not make much difference. (And when vectorizing you do *not* want an array of structs!)

Comment: The default of static schedule with maximum chunks inherently keeps the threads in distinct pages. If on a NUMA platform you must observe consistent 1st touch access to avoid Remote memory access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First question: Is it possible to split the arrays A,B,C,D and put them into different memory banks using OpenMP?

By my knowledge, no, you cannot split arrays explicitly with OpenMP runtime functions. What OpenMP do is to attribute equal load of work to each thread. Let's say you have defined **OMP_NUM_THREADS=10**, then each thread will receive 100000 iterations to execute. Or last thread will receive less work if remainder not equals to 0. (What you can do is assign thread affinity to cores.)

- Second question: If I split the arrays A,B,C,D into smaller arrays, will they speed up the execution of the loop?

No. But you can increase the number of threads to obtain better performance (until at a point that threads' overheads overtake the acceleration)

Comment: This won't do anything in his case.

Comment: @Qubit, he asked two questions, he expects some answers right? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Sure, but increasing the number of threads will do nothing for him, if he is in fact saturating the memory controller.